# USB isolated HUB : USB Data In series component identification

Tags: usb, usb-hub, isolator

What is this IC/component (L17) that is in series with the USB 2.0 D+, D- data lines?

The PCB is a Isolated industrial graded USB hub. (Only its upstream is isolated). Each downstream port has a [USBLC6-4 ESD protector](https://gr.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/usblc6_4-1852747.pdf) and before entering the IC, the L17 is in series with the data lines.

the L17 It does not have any -visible- markings on it (so it has no orientation I guess) and it is placed on the downstream ports only.

Downstreams:

[image: USB hub isolated downstream]

Upstream:

[image: USB hub isolated upstream]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L17 is a common-mode choke. A number of manufacturers make common-mode chokes rated and suitable for USB data transmission.

Comment: Why the upstream does not have a common mode choke though?

Comment: I don't know, but generally you don't add componets that are not needed. The ADUM4160 datasheet does not mention anything about common-mode chokes even if the reference design has common-mode chokes in it. But there is already 24 ohm series termination resistors which may make a common mode choke unnecessary.